# Setup Content Server

Tags: shared-hosting, content-management

This is more of a strategy question instead of a 'help with code' question.

I have a content server and need to supply content to various shared hosting and would love to know how you guys would set this up.  We would like the content to be 'cached' on the servers so that is appears as static (and to reduce the load on the content server).

Any help would be appreciated.  The basic question is regarding how you would deliver and then handle the content for the shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to use [rsync](http://www.samba.org/rsync/) to keep the "slave" servers in sync with the "master" server. The slaves are then configured to simply display the local files. rsync will make sure that files are copied efficiently and correctly (including time stamps and permissions). It will also make sure that clients don't see partial files and it will return useful error codes, and many more issues that only someone who has been doing this for decades would think of.